# I defined a command in compose.yml like command: "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" it works fine. But when I built t

Tags: python, docker

I defined a command in compose.yml like `command: "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"` and a port mapping when I try `docker-compose up`  it works fine.
But when I built the image and try to run `docker run image` it exit immediately.
Only things like `docker run -d -p 8000:8000 twitch_test_app python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` works even though I already defined the command and the port mapping in docker-compose.yml.

Is there any way to just run ```docker run image without repeating the command that is defined in compose.yml file?

Thanks alot.

Comment: What's the command defined in your images `Dockerfile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confused between docker-compose and docker.
Think docker-compose as a helper utility that help you easily setup docker environment. When you do docker-compose up, it will create a new image and setup docker container for you with all the configuration that you have specified. Your application will run inside the docker container. Docker-compose just makes life little easier.

However, if you want to just use the docker command you need to specify the same port-mapping and other configurations in the dockerfile itself.

When you do `docker run image` it will create container for you. But you need to provide entrypoint or command to start your application otherwise it will just exit as docker does not know what to do next. In your case I suppose is a Django project and you need to specify `"python manage.py runserver"` to start your django server. In dockerfile you can specify it using `CMD` attribute:

```
CMD [ "python", "manage.py", "runserver" ]
```